# C# txt file to listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I am skipping the first 2 lines in the file and have managed to display my text from my .txt file in my list box using the following code

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\James Dunn\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Assignment 2\Assignment 2\MyJukeBox\bin\Debug\Media\Other.txt");

        mediaLibrary[0] = genreListBox;

for (int l = 2; l < lines.Length; l++)
            {
                mediaLibrary[0].Items.Add(lines[l]);
            }
        genreListBox.Items.Add(mediaLibrary);
```

But this also displays  ListBox[] Array underneath my list. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears `genreListBox` is your `ListBox`, and `mediaLibrary` is an array of list boxes. I'm not sure what you're going for here, but adding `mediaLibrary` to the `genreListBox` items will cause the behavior you're seeing (it's calling `ToString()` on your `ListBox` array).

You can probably just omit that line.

Comment: Thank you I have corrected the line to genreListBox.Items.Add(mediaLibrary[0]); it now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line:
    `genreListBox.Items.Add(mediaLibrary);` or at least, this is the line that adds ListBox[] Array into your list items... if you want to add the item at [0] then do that... but without more information i'm not sure what you're trying to do...

however, if i were to add each line to a listbox, this is how you would do what you want to do:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\James Dunn\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Assignment 2\Assignment 2\MyJukeBox\bin\Debug\Media\Other.txt");

for (int l = 2; l < lines.Length; l++)
            {
                yourDropDownList.Items.Add(lines[l]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\James Dunn\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Assignment 2\Assignment 2\MyJukeBox\bin\Debug\Media\Other.txt");

genreListBox.Items.AddRange(lines);
```